# Link between Solr and Lucene

Tags: solr, lucene

Ok fine, I understood what is solr and luncene.

```
But what is the link between Solr solrconfix.xml and Schema.xml with lucene ... 
Is Solr API are different from lucene.
Can I modify solr index from lucene code ??
```

Thanks

Comment: Did the answers help with you question? If so, please accept the answer that helped you most. Otherwise, edit your question. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Lucene is a token matching and scoring library written in Java. It's core feature is information retrieval and it is used mostly for indexing and searching text.

Solr is an enterprise search server that uses the *Lucene Core* library internally.

`solrconfig.xml` is a configuration file for solr specific settings per core. The `schema.xml` defines what fields get index and how. In Lucene you would have to write Java Code to get the same functionality.

The API of Solr and Lucene is different (HTTP/XML/JSON vs. native Java API) but the Query Language is very similar due to the fact that Solr uses Lucene internally.

I guess you could modify data in Solr using lucene, since Solr itself does the same. But I highly remmond **not** doing so, especially not when Solr is running.

Answer (score 0):

Lucene is the Core Search Library in Java and it exposes the API for use.
Solr is a Search engine and more than a wrapper over Lucene to expose search features and much more in a very simplified configuration driven approach.

The Complete list is mentioned [here](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/features.html)

There are other Search engines like ElasticSearch which basically are built over Lucene search library

The schema.xml and solrconfig.xml are the configuration files which define how the index and search would behave. These configuration actually are wrapper over lucene apis.

This makes it easy for Developers without any knowledge of APIs still to easily configure the Search.

Solr underlying uses Lucene and its index format.
So Solr works on Lucene Index. You can still use the Lucene apis to read the index, but with Solr and Clients in various languages its much easy to do it.